# Find out WhatID related Name within PostToChatter body in Flow

Tags: apex, soql

I created a automatic chatter message on event using PostToChatter

my event are mostly related to opportunity
In the body of my chatter I would like to display the name of the related opportunity

If I use WhatID it will display the ID and since I do not know all the ID by heart I would need to display them.
I tried whatId__r.Name without success

How could I do it ?

Comment: A quick Internet search finds [this relatively recent posting](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A93ZFSAZ).

Comment: in soql, the relationship is called `What.Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the type of the SObject from the `Id` and then use [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to get the name:

```
Id whatId = ...;
String name = (String) Database.query(''
    + ' select Name'
    + ' from ' + whatId.getSObjectType()
    + ' where Id = :whatId'
).get('Name');
```

Comment: In a pure apex call YES you asre right .. my issue is doing the within a flow ...

Comment: Hi @Ben2pop, Best emphasise that in the title or question body.

Comment: I agree,  modified ;)